# Build against a library but not include it in the jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm converting an existing codebase to build via Maven. I set up my dependencies properly, but Maven is actually including all of the compiled dependency files in the resulting jar. I want to be able to choose which dependencies are included and which are merely linked against but not included. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at this link and read up on "dependency scopes"

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Okay, so it seems that I want to declare the dependencies as "provided". Great, thanks!